# Two Onelinner For Cycle for list and grep Bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep, gzip

I have a list of files with the following schema

```
YYYYMMDD.tar.gz
```

And I want to zcat to each one of them (I dont have zgrep) and then grep each one of them like this

```
grep --color=always "STRING" | grep 29000000.00 | grep --color=always string
```

For the zcat the below is working:

```
for archivos in $(ls -ltrh 2017091*.tar.gz); do zcat $archivos ; done
```

If I nested in two for cycles:

```
for archivos in $(ls -ltrh 2017091*.tar.gz)
do 
    for subarchivos in $(zcat $archivos)
    do 
        grep --color=always 29000000.00
    done
done
```

And I get

```
gzip: invalid option -- 'w'
Try `gzip --help' for more information.
gzip: 1.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: file.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: file.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: 357M.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: file3.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: 11.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: 00:00.gz: No such file or directory
```

And just stays there I think is to heavy and is taking a lot of time and I cannot see if it is really working could someone help me?

Comment: Look at the output of just `ls -ltrh`. You loop over all the extra information such as permissions, number of links, owner etc., but you want just the file name. Instead, you could do something like `for f in 2017091*.tar.gz; do ...`

Comment: For a recommendation on how to improve the inner loop, you have to show the example contents of one of the files. Also, your `grep` command has no input, did you mean `grep --color=always '29000000.00' "$subarchivos"`?

Comment: All you need in `for archivos in 2017091*.tar.gz;`.  The `ls` is unnecessary.

Comment: Your grep isn't doing anything. Just use one loop like:
`for archivos in 2017091*.tar.gz;do zcat $archivos | grep --color=always "STRING" | grep 29000000.00 | grep --color=always string; done`

Comment: Also, only the last grep's color options will be noticeable on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for archivos in $(ls -ltrh 2017091*.tar.gz); do zcat $archivos ; done
> ```

If you're going to parse ls's output you need to leave out all of those flags. You only want it to print file names, not sizes and permissions and such. Get rid of `-ltrh`.

Except, really, [you shouldn't parse the output of ls.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Instead, just pass all the file names to zcat.

```
zcat 2017091*.tar.gz
```

> If I nested in two for cycles:
>
> ```
> for archivos in $(ls -ltrh 2017091*.tar.gz)
> do 
>     for subarchivos in $(zcat $archivos)
>     do 
>         grep --color=always 29000000.00
>     done
> done
> ```

You wouldn't want to run `grep` repeatedly. Instead, you want to run a series of `zcat`s and pipe the output of all of them to grep. To do that, you'd pipe the *entire for loop* to `grep`:

```
for archivos in $(ls -ltrh 2017091*.tar.gz)
do
    zcat "$archivos"
done | grep --color=always 29000000.00
```

And then as discussed above, you don't need a `for` loop at all.

```
zcat 2017091*.tar.gz | grep --color=always 29000000.00
```

For what it's worth, I don't recommend using `--color=always`. If you pipe your script's output to more commands for additional processing the color codes will mess things up. `--color=auto` is better.

```
zcat 2017091*.tar.gz | grep --color=auto 29000000.00
```